# Cross validation with DNN classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation

I have a body of code to get the accuracy of DNN classification with TensorFlow, actually, I have two classes. The process of train and test is done by train_test_split in sklearn.model_selection.
Now I want to use stratified cross-validation instead of train_test_split. What I've tried is that I used
cross_val_score in sklearn.model_selection:

```
model = learn.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[5],
 n_classes=3,
 feature_columns=feature_columns, )
    scores = cross_val_score(estimator=model,
 X,
 y,
 scoring = 'accuracy',
 cv=5,
 fit_params={'steps': 1000}, verbose=100)
```

Yet I stumbled upon an error telling the tf. estimator.DNNClassifier doesn't have the fit method.
How can I get my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier),  you should be using `model.train` rather than `model.fit`.  However, instead of `DNNClassifier`, a Sequential model or Functional API is more common. You can do `model.fit` with those.

[For example](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate),

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,), name="digits")
x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_1")(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_2")(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax", name="predictions")(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=2,
    # We pass some validation for
    # monitoring validation loss and metrics
    # at the end of each epoch
    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
)
```

Or (a [quick project](https://github.com/sharonchoong/covid19tweets/blob/main/Emotion%20Classification/Emotion%20Classification.ipynb) from my repo):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=maxlen, trainable=True))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(256, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(layers.Dense(28, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0002), loss='binary_crossentropy', 
              metrics=["accuracy", metrics.Precision(name="precision"), metrics.Recall(name="recall") ])
model.summary()

callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2),
         ModelCheckpoint(filepath='best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)]
fit = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=15, verbose=True, callbacks=callbacks, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), batch_size=100)
```